ajax does not activated in codeigniter3 view page
i have following form submission in codeigniter3 view blade php code:
{!! form_open('#',array('class'=>'text-left mt-2','id'=>'BOS_FORM','onsubmit'=>"ajax(this,'".$user_base_url."/profil/profil_yonetimi_bos_duzenle');return false;")) !!}
<input  type="hidden" name="AJAX_ISLEM" value="BOS_DUZENLE">
<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="{{@$AKTIF_PROFIL->id}}">

......
{!! form_close() !!} 

but onsubmit, the ajax does not activated to send the hidden value ID to controller.
why and how should i fix that?
